# AngularJS View not updated after model changed with setTimeout

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

I have a login function which fetches user data from my back end and store it in device's local storage.

on my profile view, I retrieve the user data from the local storage and parse it as a json, it successfully fetches the data on first login attempt, but when i log in to another account the view is not updated even though the values of user data from the local storage changes.

below is my code for the login and profile controller

```
var app = angular.module('starter.controllers', []);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function(apiURL, $scope, $state, $http, $ionicLoading,$ionicPopup) {

var userData =localStorage.getItem('user');

if (userData != null || userData != undefined) {
  $state.go('app.browse');
}

   $scope.LogIn = function() {
      var url = apiURL+'/login.php';

      var credentials = {
         username: document.getElementById('username').value, 
         pword: document.getElementById('pword').value
      };

      $http.post(url,credentials).then(function(result){
         localStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(result.data));
         $state.go('app.browse',{},{reload: true});
       }).catch(function(error){
          //error
       })
    };
});


app.controller('ProfileCtrl', function(webURL, apiURL, $scope, $stateParams, $state) {
    $scope.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    $scope.goTo = function(id){
      $state.go('app.pet',{petId:id},{reload: true});
    }

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
      setTimeout( function() {
        $scope.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
      }, 1000);

      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    };
})
```

and this is my view

```
 <div class="list">
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right">
      <img ng-src="{{url}}/{{data.userData.avatar}}" id="myImage" >
      <h2 class="cli_name">{{data.userData.cli_name}}</h2>
      <p>{{data.userData.cli_address}}<br>
         {{data.userData.cli_cont}}<br>
         {{data.userData.cli_email}}</p>
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-image" ng-click="loadImage()"></button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  ̶s̶e̶t̶T̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶(̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶ ̶{̶
  $timeout( function() {
    $scope.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  }, 1000);
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The `$timeout` service is AngularJS's wrapper for `window.setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Or use  `$applyAsync`

```
$scope.doRefresh = function() {
  $applyAsync(() => {
   $scope.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
};
```